# local osm/nominatim install

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding, nominatim

I am newbie to osm/nominatim. I set up everything correctly and loaded Florida pbf data and geocode /searches were working fine. Today I added data for Mississipi using the setup.php script with --import option and looks like the data got loaded with no errors. However I am not able to geocode any of the mississipi addresses. The old Florida addresses still geocode fine. What am I missing? What should I do after loading new osm states data? I must be missing a simple step. I am happy to post additional information as needed.

Answer (score 2):

A quick internet search for "nominatim add new country" shows several hits that lead finally to help.osm.org with this question:

[import-more-osm-files-in-to-nominatim](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/15505/import-more-osm-files-in-to-nominatim)

Please tell us about success or failure.

In case that you already followed exactly this instruction, examine your import log files.